# How can filter a field based on other field value Flux

Tags: python, filter, flux

How can filter the value timestamp based on a specific value of user? I've tried the following but not returning results. I want to show the timestamp values uniquely. Both timestamp and user are fields within mqtt_consumer.

```
from(bucket: "manager")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mqtt_consumer")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "timestamp")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "user" and r["_value"] == 225)
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to pivot the results first, but it might not be the most efficient way (see discussion here [GitHub](https://github.com/influxdata/flux/issues/3078))
In your case this would be something like:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/v1"
from(bucket: "manager")
 |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mqtt_consumer")
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "timestamp" or r["_field"] == "user")
 |> v1.fieldsAsCols()
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["user"] == 255
```